# how to pass the varible into one function to another function and call the fuction in plain text and show the value in the plain text in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im getting hexadecimal encoded value in the response. i have written code for hexa to ascii but i don't know how to pass the variable to the function and call the function to show decoded data in the plain text.getting error - names undefined

code

```
 <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('url', {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic a2VybmVs==' }
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.names = response.data;             

                });
             });
    </script>
    <script>
        function hex_to_ascii(str1) {
            var hex = str1.toString();
            var str = '';
            for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
                str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
            }
            return str;
        }
        </script>
<h2>hex_to_ascii(names.hexadata)</h2>
```

Comment: You want to access `hex_to_ascii` in view?

Comment: You should format the data in the controller. Call a 'parse' function after you receive the data, and put the already parsed data on the scope. Another option is to put the parse function (hex to ascii) on the scope and call it instead of the data itself.

Comment: $scope.names  is array or object??\

Comment: its an json object.one of the node is hexadata which is in encoded hexadec format. i want to decode that and show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a mind you can change the model object name your wish.

```
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
```

And please merge your js code with angular and do the debug like as below

```
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
{
$scope.hex_to_ascii = function (str1) { 
var hex = str1.toString();
var str = '';
for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) 
{ 
str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16)); 
} 
return str; 
} 

$http.get('url',
{ 
headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic a2VybmVs==' 
} 
}).then(function (response) 
{ 
$scope.names = response.data; 
$scope.name = hex_to_ascii($scope.names.hexadata); 
});        
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: actually in names i have lot more data/fields, i need one  more scope where i want to show only hexadata field.

Comment: Yes, that is I mentioned in the first line. I have update my answer as well

Comment: error- hex_to_ascii is not defined and where str1 is used?

Comment: str1 is a parameter of `hex_to_ascii ` . and please use my updated code now. I hope you it will solve your all problems :P

Comment: still getting  hex_to_ascii is not defined.

Comment: did you used `<h2>{{name}}</h2>` in your html or your old one? I think you using your old code in your controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132096/discussion-between-swapna-and-ramesh-rajendran).